# I want to remove the message from validation: [magento 2]

Tags: magento2

[image: remove this message]

I want to remove the text :

```
"This is a required field."
```

**from the validation.**

Comment: Are you trying to remove the validation?

Comment: No @RajMohanR 
I am trying to remove the validation error Message

Answer (score 2):

You are on the wrong track. You can change this attribute to not required attribute from Magento Admin.

Navigate to Admin -> Store -> Product Attributes -> Select Size Attribute -> Make selection of Required option from Yes to No.

Comment: Will it remove validation from frontend too?? and a product has a size attribute how is it possible for add a product without attribute selection??

Comment: I agreed with @PrathapGunasekaran

Comment: And also @SIDDHANTJAIN there is no point in removing the message and that doesn't make sense mate. The question is to you actually. What's the purpose of removing then how come customers know that this one is blocking to add a product to cart.

Comment: @PrathapGunasekaran, Yes it will, try this step & cache:flush after that and check.

Comment: so it will add a product to cart without selecting any size ?

Comment: @PrathapGunasekaran Just tell me some other steps, I want to remove the text only. 
Not from admin.

Comment: I have already Removed from other options as well... So, If you know then share some information as well.

Comment: @SIDDHANTJAIN If you want to remove it then give it display:none; don't make it complex

Comment: Then Share the css file name and steps as well. @PrathapGunasekaran

Comment: You need to inspect and get class of that particular span or any tag use it like eg : .required-class { display:none; } in you theme css

Answer (score 0):

Just go-to that input field and add a custom attribute "data-msg-required"

data-msg-(validator name)

Like..

```
<input name="qty" id="qty" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate='{"required":true}' data-msg-required=""/>
```

Comment: guide me with the location and path where to insert